# retrieve from unstructured data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

Using the SOAP API i would like to retrieve [data](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/) from a data extension.

How can I ensure uniqueness to the records which i pull?  From my understanding Data Extensions do not support an "auto increment" field.

Perhaps there is some metadata which I can rely on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in a Data Extension has a unique numeric identity column named `_CustomObjectKey`.

More info on [this wiki page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/).